# Not display post meta if empty

Tags: posts

Im in need for some help. I have a seconds to min converter I want to not display if value is either 0 of if there was no meta value inputed. I realized the it outputs "0 MIN'even if no meta value was inputed I want that to not happen.

Here's the code

```
<strong>
<?php 
$duration_in_seconds = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wpscript_duration', true );
$minutes = floor($duration_in_seconds / 60);
$seconds = $duration_in_seconds - (60 * $minutes);
echo $minutes;
echo " MIN"; 
?> 
</strong>
```

Comment: Here is the solution. [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032673/if-meta-value-is-empty-do-not-display-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use in this way-

```
<strong>
<?php 
$duration_in_seconds = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wpscript_duration', true );

if( '' != $duration_in_seconds && 0 != $duration_in_seconds ) {
    $minutes = floor($duration_in_seconds / 60);
    $seconds = $duration_in_seconds - (60 * $minutes);
    echo $minutes;
    echo " MIN";
}

?> 
</strong>
```